# Invalid prop being passed to DOM element with React Markdown

Tags: html, reactjs, markdown, material-ui, github-flavored-markdown

I'm using React, React Markdown, and Material-UI to create a fairly simple web page that includes some help docs. I'm getting the following console error:

"Warning: React does not recognize the `columnAlignment` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `columnalignment` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

When built and inspected:

```html
<table class="Component-table-207" columnalignment=","><thead><tr><th>Shortcut</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Zoom in/out</td><td>Scroll up/down with mouse</td></tr><tr><td>Down/Up Arrow</td><td>Next/Previous Document</td></tr><tr><td>Right/Left Arrow</td><td>Next/Previous Page of current Document</td></tr><tr><td>Page Up/Page Down</td><td>Jump to first/last document in the PDF queue</td></tr><tr><td>Next/Previous Page of current Document</td><td>Page Up/Page Down</td></tr><tr><td>Click drag</td><td>Pan current document</td></tr><tr><td>Ctrl+R</td><td>Refresh the editor</td></tr><tr><td>Ctrl+Z</td><td>Undo</td></tr><tr><td>Ctrl+Y</td><td>Redo</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is the code I have in my Markdown.tsx file

```
const renderers = {
  /* eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types */
  heading: ({ level, ...props }: any) => {
    let variant;
    let paragraph;

    switch (level) {
      case 1:
        variant = 'display1';
        break;
      case 2:
        variant = 'title';
        break;
      case 3:
        variant = 'subheading';
        break;
      case 4:
        variant = 'caption';
        paragraph = true;
        break;
      default:
        variant = 'body';
        break;
    }

    return <Typography {...props} gutterBottom variant={variant} paragraph={paragraph} />;
  },
  table: withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }: any) => (
    <table className={classes.table} {...props} />
  )),
  listItem: withStyles(styles)(({ classes, tight, ordered, ...props }: any) => (
    <li className={classes.listItem}>
      <Typography paragraph component="span" {...props} />
    </li>
  )),
  link: withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }: any) => (
    <a
      className={classes.link}
      {...props}
    >
    </a>
  )),
  paragraph: (props: any) => <Typography {...props} paragraph />,
  image: (props: any) => <img {...props} style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />,
};

// tslint:disable-next-line:function-name
export default function Markdown(props: any) {
  return <ReactMarkdown renderers={renderers} {...props} />;
}
```

This is the Markdown in question

```
**General Shortcuts:**

| Shortcut | Action |
| ------ | ----------- |
| Zoom in/out | Scroll up/down with mouse |
| Down/Up Arrow | Next/Previous Document |
| Right/Left Arrow | Next/Previous Page of current Document |
| Page Up/Page Down | Jump to first/last document in the PDF queue |
| Next/Previous Page of current Document | Page Up/Page Down |
| Click drag | Pan current document |
| Ctrl+R | Refresh the editor |
| Ctrl+Z | Undo |
| Ctrl+Y | Redo |
```

And rendered in the Help component like so:

```
 <div id="sealing" className={classes.section}>
   <Markdown>
     {SealingJobs}
   </Markdown>
 </div>
```

Nothing I've tried has fixed the issue. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: It can be fixed if you inspect the `props` from here `<table className={classes.table} {...props} />`. As you are blindly passing all props by spreading it to `table`, React gives warning. Just extract `columnAlignment` from `props` before you pour it there?